# Is "bat an eye over X" idiomatic?

Tags: idioms

I am wondering if I can use the idiom "bat an eye" and combine it with the preposition "over". I am not sure if this can be done, but to me this makes total sense, but maybe for native speakers this isn't the case, so I am asking.

For example:

> They were wearing dog costumes at the party, but people **didn't even
>   bat an eye over it**, because they were used to that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't bat an eye:

> To not display even a hint of an emotional response, such as consternation, annoyance, sadness, joy, etc. ([The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/didn%27t+bat+an+eye))

Usually you can take this to mean that they didn't actually notice the difference from usual, and hence didn't react to it.

> They were wearing dog costumes at the party, but people didn't **notice any change from the usual**, because they were used to that sort of thing.

I wouldn't say it was very usual to add "over it" since it's already implied by the idiom itself. I don't see any issue in adding this in though, it just adds further clarity to the sentence.

---

As pointed out by @jonathonjo, bat an eye**lid** is also idiomatic and holds an identical meaning. Infact, I believe this is where the phrase originates and has just been cut-down over the years.