# Is the idiomatic "didn't bat an eye" losing its sense if used slightly differently?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, expressions

The expression *didn't bat an eye* is [well recognized](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/218559/4926). As an idiomatic such, one has to be careful not to tamper with it too much risking its integrity. However, I did use it in a bit different grammatical form and people were surprised. They, sort of *batted the eyes*.

> Oh, this was definitely an *eye batting moment*, won't you agree?

My view is that's both obvious and a bit witty. However, I'm known to be rather inventive when it comes to grammar and vocabulary so I keep humble as a non NSE to verify whether the reality agrees with me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't think it works? perhaps describing the situation you used it in might help? On the face of it, I can't see anything wrong with it (a moment that would elicit an emotional response), but there may be context that would invalidate it's application. See the similar UkE phrase *bat an eyelid* https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+bat+an+eyelid

Comment: @Smock The only reason why I fear it didn't get through is the sensation I got from the audience's reaction. They seemed to understand the intended meaning but it felt like I could've said *...this was definitely donkey-banana moment...* and they'd guess what I mean too. Without it having officially confirmed, as the conversation went on without dwelling on this, I retained the impression that this particular expression didn't contribute to the clarity of communication. Might be my ever-so-present complex for being non-NSE, of course...

Comment: Well it seems ok to me, and I would understand it. I'm not sure how it would be witty though (again, without context)

Comment: @Smock Thanks. You might want to repost it as a answer to be accepted, in such case. As for the wittiness, perhaps I'm using the wrong word. My point is that I'm using a familiar expression in a bit modified way. Compare *woosh* which is a sound of something *wooshing you by*. If I say *woosh moment*, it's not  a common construction but a bit clever or creative compound of concepts. What would be a better term for it?

Comment: I first interpreted it in the sense of "to bat (one's) eyes at someone" - but that was obviously not what you meant. Perhaps context would've helped be distinguish it better.

Comment: Thanks @KonradViltersten but I'm not sure it really constitutes much of an answer sadly:-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't lose its idiomatic meaning if you say "eye-batting", assuming that the listener recognizes the idiom.  There should also be enough context to support the "didn't flinch" interpretation, as ["to bat one's eyes"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bat+her+eyes) means something else entirely.

As for whether it's clever ... well, to me it sounds a little forced, but then again cleverness is all about context.  It would be fine, for example, in a situation where you were playing off of someone else using the standard idiom, especially if their use was slightly awkward and you wanted to draw attention to it:

> Alecia:  When the teacher called on me, I didn't *bat an eye*.  I stood right up and gave the answer.
>   Bart:  We're glad you did because there was plenty of **eye-batting** from the rest of us.  We didn't have a clue.